# Coredata magicalrecord fetching objects in background go in <fault> state

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using the MagicalRecord lib to load in some CoreData objects which are used to populate a tableview. This a slow operation thus I'm trying to do this on a background threat. 
This all seems to go well, the data is loaded into `self.products`, only after a some time (+- minutes) all the loaded objects seem to go into `<fault>` state. I don't see why this is happening, anyone an idea ?

```
- (void)doInBackground
{
 dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);
    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        [self reloadData];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread: @selector(sortData:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];

        });
    });
}

- (void)reloadData
{
 NSArray *allProducts = [NSArray array];    
 allProducts =   [NSArray arrayWithArray:[Product MR_findAll]];
 self.products = [NSArray arrayWithArray:allProducts];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are using, implicitly, the default context by only using MR_findAll without specifying a context. This will eventually lead to crashes or other unknown behavior. Second, you don't need all those NSArrays. The return value of MR_findAll (and all other MR_find* methods) return an array of results. No need for moving contents from array to array to array...

And lastly, your question. Because you're doing a fetch on the Main Context queue, your fetches will block the UI regardless. You need to make a Private Queue context and perform your fetches with that, like so:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *privateQueueContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_privateQueueContext];
NSArray *results = [Product MR_findAllInContext:privateQueueContext];
```

Also, you may want to look into batching your fetches. Look at the docs about getting a fetch request like so:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [Product MR_requestAllInContext:privateQueueContext];
//update batch size here
```

MagicalRecord has a batch size set internally, but if you need to change it, this is the way you go about doing that.

Comment: I'm sorry but this somewhat confusing, MR_privateQueueContext is not recognized by MagicalRecord. Could you rewrite my code to something that would resolve the problem where the objects fetched go into <fault> state ?

Comment: MR_privateQueueContext is on the features/experimental branch. Try switching to that for now while I sort out the details of getting some of the experimental features back into the develop/master mainline.

Comment: @casademora I'm having the same issue of slow fetching causing UI blocking. There is no known class method for MR_privateQueueContext. I know you suggested switching to an experimental branch but I was wondering if there's a sure way to handle this?